# Jmeter Load testing website over a period of time/required duration

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

How can I simulate multiple sessions(users) staying on  website for long duration (say over 15 minutes) and making multiple requests in jmeter(load testing)

Answer (score 5):

You can check the loop count as forever in the thread group, this will help you to hit the api for longer duration.
Or 
You can use the Scheduler in the thread group and set the start and end time which meets your time requirement.
[Check the snapshot of the thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHLJg.png)

Comment: In addition to what Sumukh stated, if you specify a Start/Stop time in the past you can set the Duration field so the test can run on-demand for the specified time (in seconds). So for example, if the Start/Stop times are for yesterday and Duration = 1800, when you run the test tomorrow, the Thread Group will run for 30 minutes. I do this for my regression test on a Jenkins server without having to continually changing the Start/Stop dates & times.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/). It's a **JMeter Plugin** which is available in [standard set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/).

In **Ultimate Thread group** you can configure like this:

[image]

In the above example, it **holds the load for 60 seconds(1 minute) for 100 users.**

To see the **concurrency**, you can use [Active Threads Over Time Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) which will give you a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the jMeter Plugins [ConcurrencyThreadGroup](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) or even [UltimateThreadGroup](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/), which allow you to configure permanent loads, i.e. you can set the amount of concurrent users (parameter `target concurrency`) for 15 minutes (parameter `hold target rate time`). (Even better, you can increase the load in a stepwise manner to figure out when the server gets into trouble.)